# Calling `std::get` on `std::tuple` with elements deriving from `std::tuple` - ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, libstdc++, stdtuple

```
struct Y { };
struct X : std::tuple<Y> { };

int main()
{
    std::get<0>(std::make_tuple(X{}));
}
```

[**on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mnoIClXREPXKGqaC)

---

The above code compiles and works as expected with `clang++` when using **libc++**.

The above code fails to compile with both `clang++` and `g++` when using **libstdc++** with the following error:

```
include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1302:36: 
error: no matching function for call to ‘__get_helper<0>(std::tuple<X>&)’
    { return std::__get_helper<__i>(__t); }
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1290:5: 
note: candidate: template<long unsigned int __i, class _Head, class ... _Tail> 
                constexpr _Head& std::__get_helper(std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&)
    __get_helper(_Tuple_impl<__i, _Head, _Tail...>& __t) noexcept
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~

include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1290:5: 
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1302:36: 
note:   ‘std::_Tuple_impl<0, _Head, _Tail ...>’ is an ambiguous base class of ‘std::tuple<X>’
    { return std::__get_helper<__i>(__t); }
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~

include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1295:5: 
note: candidate: template<long unsigned int __i, class _Head, class ... _Tail> 
                constexpr const _Head& std::__get_helper(const std::_Tuple_impl<_Idx, _Head, _Tail ...>&)
    __get_helper(const _Tuple_impl<__i, _Head, _Tail...>& __t) noexcept
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~

include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1295:5: 
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
include/c++/7.0.1/tuple:1302:36: 
note:   ‘const std::_Tuple_impl<0, _Head, _Tail ...>’ is an ambiguous base class of ‘std::tuple<X>’
    { return std::__get_helper<__i>(__t); }
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

It seems that **libstdc++**'s inheritance-based implementation of `std::tuple` causes ambiguity when tuple elements derive from `std::tuple` upon calling `std::get`. I'm inclined to think that this is an implementation defect in **libstdc++** - is that the case? Or is there something in the Standard that would make the code snippet ill-formed?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) in the comments, this is caused by the [known bug #71096](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71096).